# RewriteRule mp3 to php

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, regex

I want to rewrite all .mp3 files to a php file. And I dont want to pass on the path

so
http://localhost/somepath/feb.mp3
http://localhost/feb.mp3

shouldn't do any difference.

I came up with:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.mp3$ /files/read/?file=$1.mp3 [QSA]
```

What am I missing? maybe some regexp before the (.*) but why doesn't it pick up the mp3 pattern and redirect to /files/read/?file=feb.mp3 ?

This doesn't even seem to catch the mp3 files:

```
applying pattern '^(.*)\.mp3$' to uri 'feb.mp3'
```

It doesn't stop there, it goes through the other condition and falls under:

```
applying pattern '^.*$' to uri 'feb.mp3'
pass through /htdocs/project/project-web/feb.mp3
```

Many thanks if this can be solved.

this is my full .htaccess

SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.mp3$ files/read/?file=$1.mp3 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

This seem to work, however it redirects it.

```
 RewriteRule ^(.+).mp3$ http://education.localhost/files/read/?file=$1.mp3 [NC,L]
```

It could be something that when this rewrite rule does apply, then this does not:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

So files/read/?file=$1.mp3 this is dependent on that role to index.php, any way to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Make the rewriting process stop when an MP3 is found instead of sending the request to `index.php`, use the `[L]` flag.

And to make it not care what the directory path is preceding the MP3 filename, you'll want to exclude anything before the last slash character.

So, try this:

```
RewriteRule ([^/]*)\.mp3$ files/read/?file=$1.mp3 [QSA,L]
```

Or, did you mean to actually redirect the client, and still let it hit index.php on the subsequent request?  I'm guessing so, since it's a query parameter... try this:

```
RewriteRule ([^/]*)\.mp3$ files/read/?file=$1.mp3 [QSA,L,R=301]
```